# iOS - save to log file and extract later

Tags: ios, swift, logging, nslog

So i am trying to save a log file and then open it in my office.

I have tried "Willow" and "CocoaLumberjack" yet i fail.

I have tried the open console yet it shows logs only from the time i connected the device to the mac.
Also tried:

```
NSLog("example")
```

and

```
let customLog = OSLog(subsystem: "com.your_company.your_subsystem_name", category: "Category")
os_log("This is info that may be helpful during development or debugging.", log: customLog, type: .debug)
```

Am i doing something wrong or there is other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i managed to do so with "CocoaLumberjack" pod.

Pretty much as in the documentation.

I have created a file like so:

```
import Foundation
import CocoaLumberjack

func setupLogging() {
   DDLog.add(DDOSLogger.sharedInstance) // Uses os_log
   let fileLogger: DDFileLogger = DDFileLogger() // File Logger
   fileLogger.rollingFrequency = 60 * 60 * 24 // 24 hours
   fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 7
   DDLog.add(fileLogger)
}

func writeLog(message: String) {
   DDLogDebug(message)
}
```

In appDelegate i did this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    setupLogging()
    return true
}
```

And then wherever i wanted to write a log i did like so:

```
writeLog(message: "test")
```

After finishing i had to extract the log like so:
windows -> devices and simulator -> choose the device -> choose the app -> scroll down to the gear icon -> download container -> then show package contents -> library/caches/logs
:)